Mappings that preserve local or global minimum
In the most general form, I'm interested in any non-trivial results of the following question.

Consider metric space $X$ and $Y$, denote all real valued functions on $X$ and $Y$ as $\mathbb{R}^{X}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{Y}$. Let $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ be some subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{X}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{Y}$. We say $h:\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$ and $l:X\to Y$ preserves local(global) minimum if for any $f \in \mathcal{ F}$, $x\in X$ is a local (global) minimum of $f$ if and only if $l(x)$ is also a local (global) minimum of $h(f)$. How can we characterize all functions $h$ and $l$ that preserve local (global) minimum?

In the simple case where $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ are continuous functions, and assuming $l$ is the identity. Intuitively, I think local mins basically fix the rough shape, so $h$ just modifies the part between local minimum. One interesting case is that we can take $f^{* *}$, or also known as the biconjugate, which is a convex closure of $f$ when $f$ is closed, thus $f^{* *}$ has the same global minimum as $f$. There are other simple ways to transform functions, but I cannot think of any non-trivial results. For instance, what if we consider only linear functionals?
I was reading a paper and thought about this, for instance $\mathcal{F}$ can space of (signed) measures, with $X$ being the sigma-algebra, and $\mathcal{G}$ being functions of linear combination of moments. Also, in polynomial optimization, the simple idea is just $\operatorname{min}_{{x \in K}} f(x) = \operatorname{min}_{\mu \in \mathcal{B}(K),\mu(K)=1} \int f \, d\mu$, where $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ compact, and $f$ is a polynomial. Broadly speaking, this basically transformed the global minimum of nonconvex polynomials to the minimum convex program.

Inspired by these observations, I'm interested in hearing non-trivial results on characterizations of mappings that preserve local (global) minimum. Any assumption on the spaces are fine, I mostly want to gain some intuition on this.


In your  question are you  also interested  to   consider  the  contravariant case  $\ell:X\to Y$  but $h:\mathcal{G} to \mathcal{F}$? In this  case  every  continuous  function $\ell:X\to  Y$ gives  a  natural pull back $h:=\ell^*: C(Y) \to  C(X)$  with the  property you  mentioned. I like  your  question because it can be  applied to  every  possible category

@AliTaghavi That sounds interesting, can you elaborate here or in the answer section?

Thank  you  for  your  comment.  To  be  honnest my  comment is  not significant and  is not  worth of  an  answer. I  will think  a little  more and  come  back here with  possible  elaboration  on your interesting  question. I  belive that an  algebraic  formulation of  your  question is  an interesting  problem
